# How to create an interactive brain-shaped graph?

Tags: python, plotly, networkx

I'm working on a visualization project in `networkx` and `plotly`. Is there a way to create a 3D graph that resembles how a human brain looks like in `networkx` and then to visualize it with `plotly` (so it will be interactive)?
[image]

The idea is to have the nodes on the outside (or only show the nodes if it's easier) and to color a set of them differently like the image above

Comment: Following up here from your comments on my first answer.  So you're looking for a way to take an arbitrary graph (that isn't necessarily brain data -- just any graph) and map it onto 3D coordinate surface that looks like a human brain then plot with plotly?

Comment: @Frodnar Yes, exactly

Comment: One final question: are you looking to highlight/color the differentiated nodes only (easiest and most likely to happen before bounty expiry)?  Nodes and any edges which have both nodes highlighted?  The surface roughly bounded by highlighted nodes?

Comment: @Frodnar I didn't quite understand the question. Are you asking if I want to color only the nodes or the nodes and the edges?

Comment: Yeah, basically.  I'm also asking if you want the area of the brain surface to be colored as well just because that's what it looks like in the image you put in your question, but I'll be calling it close on the bounty just with nodes OR nodes + edges (i.e. I won't have time to figure out how to color the surface separately).

Comment: @Frodnar Just the nodes is perfectly fine. I was hoping that the nodes will take the shape of the brain, but sounds like you're thinking about having the nodes on a fixed surface that is the shape of a brain? In that case as long as that surface is relatively clear in color (like the image) so the nodes' colors will be visible that will be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the clarified requirements, I took a new approach:

1. Download accurate brain mesh data from [BrainNet Viewer github repo](https://github.com/mingruixia/BrainNet-Viewer/tree/master/Data/SurfTemplate);
2. Plot a random graph with 3D-coordinates using [Kamada-Kuwai cost function](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.kamada_kawai_layout.html) in three dimensions centered in a sphere containing the brain mesh;
3. Radially expand the node positions away from the center of the brain mesh and then shift them back to the closest vertex actually on the brain mesh;
4. Color some nodes red based on an arbitrary distance criterion from a randomly selected mesh vertex;
5. Fiddle with a bunch of plotting parameters to make it look decent.

There is a clearly delineated spot to add in different graph data as well as change the logic by which the node colors are decided.  The key parameters to play with so that things look decent after introducing new graph data are:

- `scale_factor`: This changes how much the original Kamada-Kuwai calculated coordinates are translated radially away from the center of the brain mesh before they are snapped back to its surface.  Larger values will make more nodes snap to the outer surface of the brain.  Smaller values will leave more nodes positioned on the surfaces between the two hemispheres.
- `opacity` of the lines in the edge trace:  Graphs with more edges will quickly clutter up field of view and make the overall brain shape less visible.  This speaks to my biggest dissatisfaction with this overall approach -- that edges which appear outside of the mesh surface make it harder to see the overall shape of the mesh, especially between the temporal lobes.

My other biggest caveat here is that there is no attempt has been made to check whether any nodes positioned on the brain surface happen to *coincide* or have any sort of equal spacing.

Here is a screenshot and the [live demo on Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Frodnar/so_questions/blob/main/69805091/69805091_answer2.ipynb).  Full copy-pasteable code below.

[image: brain_network_on_surface]

There are a whole bunch of asides that could be discussed here, but for brevity I will only note two:

1. Folks interested in this topic but feeling overwhelmed by programming details should absolutely check out [BrainNet Viewer](https://www.nitrc.org/projects/bnv/);
2. There are plenty of other brain meshes in the [BrainNet Viewer github repo](https://github.com/mingruixia/BrainNet-Viewer/tree/master/Data/SurfTemplate) that could be used.  Even better, if you have any mesh which can be formatted or reworked to be compatible with this approach, you could at least **try wrapping a set of nodes around any other non-brain and somewhat round-ish mesh representing any other object**.

---

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import math

    
def mesh_properties(mesh_coords):
    """Calculate center and radius of sphere minimally containing a 3-D mesh
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    mesh_coords : tuple
        3-tuple with x-, y-, and z-coordinates (respectively) of 3-D mesh vertices
    """

    radii = []
    center = []

    for coords in mesh_coords:
        c_max = max(c for c in coords)
        c_min = min(c for c in coords)
        center.append((c_max + c_min) / 2)

        radius = (c_max - c_min) / 2
        radii.append(radius)

    return(center, max(radii))


# Download and prepare dataset from BrainNet repo
coords = np.loadtxt(np.DataSource().open('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mingruixia/BrainNet-Viewer/master/Data/SurfTemplate/BrainMesh_Ch2_smoothed.nv'), skiprows=1, max_rows=53469)
x, y, z = coords.T

triangles = np.loadtxt(np.DataSource().open('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mingruixia/BrainNet-Viewer/master/Data/SurfTemplate/BrainMesh_Ch2_smoothed.nv'), skiprows=53471, dtype=int)
triangles_zero_offset = triangles - 1
i, j, k = triangles_zero_offset.T

# Generate 3D mesh.  Simply replace with 'fig = go.Figure()' or turn opacity to zero if seeing brain mesh is not desired.
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Mesh3d(x=x, y=y, z=z,
                                 i=i, j=j, k=k,
                                 color='lightpink', opacity=0.5, name='', showscale=False, hoverinfo='none')])

# Generate networkx graph and initial 3-D positions using Kamada-Kawai path-length cost-function inside sphere containing brain mesh
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(200, 0.02, seed=42) # Replace G with desired graph here

mesh_coords = (x, y, z)
mesh_center, mesh_radius = mesh_properties(mesh_coords)

scale_factor = 5 # Tune this value by hand to have more/fewer points between the brain hemispheres.
pos_3d = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G, dim=3, center=mesh_center, scale=scale_factor*mesh_radius) 

# Calculate final node positions on brain surface
pos_brain = {}

for node, position in pos_3d.items():
    squared_dist_matrix = np.sum((coords - position) ** 2, axis=1)
    pos_brain[node] = coords[np.argmin(squared_dist_matrix)]

# Prepare networkx graph positions for plotly node and edge traces
nodes_x = [position[0] for position in pos_brain.values()]
nodes_y = [position[1] for position in pos_brain.values()]
nodes_z = [position[2] for position in pos_brain.values()]

edge_x = []
edge_y = []
edge_z = []
for s, t in G.edges():
    edge_x += [nodes_x[s], nodes_x[t]]
    edge_y += [nodes_y[s], nodes_y[t]]
    edge_z += [nodes_z[s], nodes_z[t]]

# Decide some more meaningful logic for coloring certain nodes.  Currently the squared distance from the mesh point at index 42.
node_colors = []
for node in G.nodes():
    if np.sum((pos_brain[node] - coords[42]) ** 2) < 1000:
        node_colors.append('red')
    else:
        node_colors.append('gray')

# Add node plotly trace
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=nodes_x, y=nodes_y, z=nodes_z,
                           #text=labels,
                           mode='markers', 
                           #hoverinfo='text',
                           name='Nodes',
                           marker=dict(
                                       size=5,
                                       color=node_colors
                                      )
                           ))

# Add edge plotly trace.  Comment out or turn opacity to zero if not desired.
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=edge_x, y=edge_y, z=edge_z,
                           mode='lines',
                           hoverinfo='none',
                           name='Edges',
                           opacity=0.1, 
                           line=dict(color='gray')
                           ))

# Make axes invisible
fig.update_scenes(xaxis_visible=False,
                  yaxis_visible=False,
                  zaxis_visible=False)

# Manually adjust size of figure
fig.update_layout(autosize=False,
                  width=800,
                  height=800)

fig.show()
```

Comment: @Penguin Thanks for the awesome question.  Definitely was an interesting one to work on.  Feel free to message me if you need any specific help or alterations.  You can find out how to contact me through my Stack Overflow profile.

Comment: @Penguin Could you let met me know if / how this was used for an ultimate application?

Answer (score 5):

To start, this code is **heavily** borrowed from Matteo Mancini, which he describes [here](https://neurosnippets.com/posts/interactive-network/) and he has [released under the MIT license](https://github.com/matteomancini/neurosnippets/blob/master/LICENSE.md).

In the original code, networkx is not used, so it's clear you don't actually need networkx to accomplish your goal.  If this is not a strict requirement, I would consider using his original code and reworking it to fit your input data.

Since you listed networkx as a requirement, I simply reworked his code to take a networkx `Graph` object with certain node attributes such as `'color'` and `'coord'` to be used for those marker characteristics in the final plotly scatter.  I just chose the first ten points in the dataset to color red, which is why they aren't grouped.

The full copy-pasteable code is below. The screenshot here obviously isn't interactive, but you can try the demo [here on Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Frodnar/so_questions/blob/main/69805091/69805091.ipynb).

[image: brain_network_plotly_from_networkx]

---

**To download files if in Jupyter notebook on Linux/Mac:**

```
!wget https://github.com/matteomancini/neurosnippets/raw/master/brainviz/interactive-network/lh.pial.obj
!wget https://github.com/matteomancini/neurosnippets/raw/master/brainviz/interactive-network/icbm_fiber_mat.txt
!wget https://github.com/matteomancini/neurosnippets/raw/master/brainviz/interactive-network/fs_region_centers_68_sort.txt
!wget https://github.com/matteomancini/neurosnippets/raw/master/brainviz/interactive-network/freesurfer_regions_68_sort_full.txt
```

- Otherwise: download the required files [here](https://github.com/matteomancini/neurosnippets/tree/master/brainviz/interactive-network).

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import networkx as nx # New dependency


def obj_data_to_mesh3d(odata):
    # odata is the string read from an obj file
    vertices = []
    faces = []
    lines = odata.splitlines()   
   
    for line in lines:
        slist = line.split()
        if slist:
            if slist[0] == 'v':
                vertex = np.array(slist[1:], dtype=float)
                vertices.append(vertex)
            elif slist[0] == 'f':
                face = []
                for k in range(1, len(slist)):
                    face.append([int(s) for s in slist[k].replace('//','/').split('/')])
                if len(face) > 3: # triangulate the n-polyonal face, n>3
                    faces.extend([[face[0][0]-1, face[k][0]-1, face[k+1][0]-1] for k in range(1, len(face)-1)])
                else:    
                    faces.append([face[j][0]-1 for j in range(len(face))])
            else: pass
    
    
    return np.array(vertices), np.array(faces)


with open("lh.pial.obj", "r") as f:
    obj_data = f.read()
[vertices, faces] = obj_data_to_mesh3d(obj_data)

vert_x, vert_y, vert_z = vertices[:,:3].T
face_i, face_j, face_k = faces.T

cmat = np.loadtxt('icbm_fiber_mat.txt')
nodes = np.loadtxt('fs_region_centers_68_sort.txt')

labels=[]
with open("freesurfer_regions_68_sort_full.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        labels.append(line.strip('\n'))

# Instantiate Graph and add nodes (with their coordinates)
G = nx.Graph()

for idx, node in enumerate(nodes):
    G.add_node(idx, coord=node)

# Add made-up colors for the nodes as node attribute
colors_data = {node: ('gray' if node > 10 else 'red') for node in G.nodes}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, colors_data, name="color")

# Add edges
[source, target] = np.nonzero(np.triu(cmat)>0.01)
edges = list(zip(source, target))

G.add_edges_from(edges)

# Get node coordinates from node attribute
nodes_x = [data['coord'][0] for node, data in G.nodes(data=True)]
nodes_y = [data['coord'][1] for node, data in G.nodes(data=True)]
nodes_z = [data['coord'][2] for node, data in G.nodes(data=True)]

edge_x = []
edge_y = []
edge_z = []
for s, t in edges:
    edge_x += [nodes_x[s], nodes_x[t]]
    edge_y += [nodes_y[s], nodes_y[t]]
    edge_z += [nodes_z[s], nodes_z[t]]

# Get node colors from node attribute
node_colors = [data['color'] for node, data in G.nodes(data=True)]

fig = go.Figure()

# Changed color and opacity kwargs
fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(x=vert_x, y=vert_y, z=vert_z, i=face_i, j=face_j, k=face_k,
                        color='gray', opacity=0.1, name='', showscale=False, hoverinfo='none'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=nodes_x, y=nodes_y, z=nodes_z, text=labels,
                           mode='markers', hoverinfo='text', name='Nodes',
                           marker=dict(
                                       size=5, # Changed node size...
                                       color=node_colors # ...and color
                                      )
                           ))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=edge_x, y=edge_y, z=edge_z,
                           mode='lines', hoverinfo='none', name='Edges',
                           opacity=0.3, # Added opacity kwarg
                           line=dict(color='pink') # Added line color
                           ))

fig.update_layout(
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(showticklabels=False, visible=False),
        yaxis=dict(showticklabels=False, visible=False),
        zaxis=dict(showticklabels=False, visible=False),
    ),
    width=800, height=600
)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Not sure if finding and slightly adjusting someone else's pre-made solution is really worth a bounty, so consider before awarding. Someone who actually uses Twitter might DM or tweet [the author of the original code](https://neurosnippets.com/about_me/) (and then comment here that you've done so to prevent spamming).  I'd like to know if my code were getting put to good use...

Comment: With the proper attribution that you've included here, this should not be a problem, should it? (+1)

Comment: This is really cool! But I don't see how to use this other than using the existing data. That is, the code is using specific coordinates for the nodes, so if I wanted to add more nodes or change the edges I'll have to either know the coordinates or play with it until it aligns. Unless I'm misunderstanding something? Usually `networkx` graph can be made from an adjacency matrix or an edge list

Comment: Do you have *some* sort of coordinate data?  I'm no expert in brain mapping, but presumably with some research you could find a way to map your coordinate data to this brain model specifically or to a de facto standard used in neuroscience.  If all you have is an adjacency matrix or edge list without any sort of 3-D coordinate data, then there is no way to say where in the brain those nodes are.  The reason you can draw graphs from networkx without those data is that they are calculated by an algorithm, usually at the time of drawing for small networks.

Comment: @Frodnar I understand. Apologies if my question was confusing, but the exact location isn't really important. I was merely looking for a way to take a common graph representation (edge list / adjacency matrix / etc.) and convert it to a 3D graph that resembles the brain. The image with the colors was an attempt (maybe poorly done on my end) to show an example of what I meant with coloring the nodes on the brain

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do that:

```
import networkx as nx
import random
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from stl import mesh

# function to convert stl 3d-model to mesh 
# Taken from : https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~empet/15276/converting-a-stl-mesh-to-plotly-gomes/#/

def stl2mesh3d(stl_mesh):
    # stl_mesh is read by nympy-stl from a stl file; it is  an array of faces/triangles (i.e. three 3d points) 
    # this function extracts the unique vertices and the lists I, J, K to define a Plotly mesh3d
    p, q, r = stl_mesh.vectors.shape #(p, 3, 3)
    # the array stl_mesh.vectors.reshape(p*q, r) can contain multiple copies of the same vertex;
    # extract unique vertices from all mesh triangles
    vertices, ixr = np.unique(stl_mesh.vectors.reshape(p*q, r), return_inverse=True, axis=0)
    I = np.take(ixr, [3*k for k in range(p)])
    J = np.take(ixr, [3*k+1 for k in range(p)])
    K = np.take(ixr, [3*k+2 for k in range(p)])
    return vertices, I, J, K

# Let's use a toy "brain" stl file. You can get it from my Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lav2opci8vekaep/brain.stl?dl=0
#
# Note: I made it quick and dirty whith Blender and is not supposed to be an accurate representation 
# of an actual brain. You can put your own model here.

my_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('brain.stl')
vertices, I, J, K = stl2mesh3d(my_mesh)
x, y, z = vertices.T    # x,y,z contain the stl vertices


# Let's generate a random spatial graph:
# Note: spatial graphs have a "pos" (position) attribute
# pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, "pos")

G = nx.random_geometric_graph(30, 0.3, dim=3)  # in dimension 3 --> pos = [x,y,z]

#nx.draw(G)
print('Nb. of nodes: ',G.number_of_nodes(), 'Nb. of edges: ',G.number_of_edges())

# Take G.number_of_nodes() of nodes and attribute them randomly to points in the list of vertices of the STL model:
# That is, we "scatter" the nodes on the brain surface:

Vec3dList=list(np.array(random.sample(list(vertices), G.number_of_nodes())))

for i in range(len(Vec3dList)):
    G.nodes[i]['pos']=Vec3dList[i]


# Create nodes and edges graph objects:
# Code from: https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/  modified to work with 3d graphs
edge_x = []
edge_y = []
edge_z = []
for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0, z0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
    x1, y1, z1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
    edge_x.append(x0)
    edge_x.append(x1)
    edge_x.append(None)
    edge_y.append(y0)
    edge_y.append(y1)
    edge_y.append(None)
    edge_z.append(z0)
    edge_z.append(z1)
    edge_z.append(None)
    

edge_trace = go.Scatter3d(
    x=edge_x, y=edge_y, z=edge_z,
    line=dict(width=2, color='#888'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    opacity=.3,
    mode='lines')

node_x = []
node_y = []
node_z = []
for node in G.nodes():
    X, Y, Z = G.nodes[node]['pos']
    node_x.append(X)
    node_y.append(Y)
    node_z.append(Z)

node_trace = go.Scatter3d(
    x=node_x, y=node_y,z=node_z,
    mode='markers',
    hoverinfo='text',
    marker=dict(
        showscale=True,
        # colorscale options
        #'Greys' | 'YlGnBu' | 'Greens' | 'YlOrRd' | 'Bluered' | 'RdBu' |
        #'Reds' | 'Blues' | 'Picnic' | 'Rainbow' | 'Portland' | 'Jet' |
        #'Hot' | 'Blackbody' | 'Earth' | 'Electric' | 'Viridis' |
        colorscale='YlGnBu',
        reversescale=True,
        color=[],
        size=5,
        colorbar=dict(
            thickness=15,
            title='Node Connections',
            xanchor='left',
            titleside='right'
        ),
        line_width=10))

node_adjacencies = []
node_text = []
for node, adjacencies in enumerate(G.adjacency()):
    node_adjacencies.append(len(adjacencies[1]))
    node_text.append('# of connections: '+str(len(adjacencies[1])))

node_trace.marker.color = node_adjacencies
node_trace.text = node_text

colorscale= [[0, '#e5dee5'], [1, '#e5dee5']]                           
mesh3D = go.Mesh3d(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z, 
            i=I, 
            j=J, 
            k=K, 
            flatshading=False,
            colorscale=colorscale, 
            intensity=z, 
            name='Brain',
            opacity=0.25,
            hoverinfo='none',
            showscale=False)


title = "Brain"
layout = go.Layout(paper_bgcolor='rgb(1,1,1)',
            title_text=title, title_x=0.5,
                   font_color='white',
            width=800,
            height=800,
            scene_camera=dict(eye=dict(x=1.25, y=-1.25, z=1)),
            scene_xaxis_visible=False,
            scene_yaxis_visible=False,
            scene_zaxis_visible=False)



fig = go.Figure(data=[mesh3D, edge_trace, node_trace], layout=layout)

fig.data[0].update(lighting=dict(ambient= .2,
                                 diffuse= 1,
                                 fresnel=  1,
                                 specular= 1,
                                 roughness= .1,
                                 facenormalsepsilon=0))
                                 
fig.data[0].update(lightposition=dict(x=3000,
                                      y=3000,
                                      z=10000));

fig.show()
```

Below, the result. As you can see the result is not that great... But, maybe, you can improve on it.
Best regards
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Vispy library might be useful https://github.com/vispy/vispy.
I think you can use the following examples.

[3D brain mesh viewer](https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/main/examples/demo/gloo/brain.py)

[1ex output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFbEa.png)

[Plot various views of a structural MRI.](https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/main/examples/plotting/volume_plot.py)

[2ex output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkhvq.png)

[Clipping planes with volume and markers](https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/main/examples/scene/clipping_planes.py)

[3ex output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuLFJ.png)

These examples are interactive.

Regards!

Comment: I don't see how to put in a graph representation (edge list/ adjacency matrix/ etc.) and get the brain shaped plot